# Logic (or possibly general production) terminology - what does 'recorded box' mean?

Tags: recording, logic-pro

I'm a singer and have been talking with a producer via email in regards to exchanging ideas/melodies on Logic. I just need to clarify what he means when he said 'Just some basic ideas with recorded box are cool.'

I haven't ever studied music so am not familiar with these phrases.

Can anyone help? I'm trying to act like I know what I'm doing ;)

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what a "recorded box" is either - but I'm not a Logic user. I do wonder if it's a typo though?

Comment: Seems like it must be. Best bet is to ask the producer what they meant.

Answer (score 2):

Given the proximity of the "b" and "v" keys on a qwerty keyboard, this is almost surely an "autocorrect" or typo for "vox" which is a common abbreviation of "vocals" (vocals -> vocs -> vox).

Answer (score 0):

Drum box perhaps?  Or B/trax  short for backing tracks.